# IOS's DownloadFont feature official code doesn't work when copy paste code in new project, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, ios6

This question is about the feature called "[DownloadFont](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DownloadFont/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013404-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_8)" implemented from IOS 6 which allows the application to download additional fonts that aren't available by default.

When I copy and paste all the source file content into the same files in a new project (single view template), I get an error "`signal SIGABRT`" from `main.m` and the message in the console is : "*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle*". However, if I download the source code entirely as a project (as available in the above link), and run it in the same version of the same IDE (xcode6 beta2), it works perfectly.

To be more precise, what I did is copy all the content from `AppDelegate.h`, `AppDelegate.m`, `ViewController.h`, `ViewController.m` and `main.m` into the same files in the new project and also put the same deployment target as the sample code (6.0), but this throws the above exception.

This may not be a problem specific to DownloadFont, but I just couldn't find out why this doesn't work.

Comment: You are missing either the storyboard .storyboard file or view controller .xib file.

Comment: Okay, that was it. Post it bellow and I'll mark you as the good answer. I had to copy paste the source's .xib file. However I still don't understand why they don't specify that this file is necessary and how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing either the storyboard `.storyboard` file or view controller `.xib` file. Both of those files are user interface files that define how the user interface should look and behave.

The example code isn't meant to be copied as a whole project, but rather typically only a code snippet at a time if you need it.